# How to change the shortcut for view Quick Documentation in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

I know that to view Quick Documentation, it's Alt/Options key + Left click.
How can i change the key to something else so that i will be able to view the documentation while viewing suggestions using (Ctrl + Space) (It's hard to check it using mouse click each time.

Those who have experience in Android Studio can understand my situation easily.

Answer (score -1):

For Xcode only , you can't change Command + Click to Control + Click.

If you want to change your MAC Shortcut Key then you can Change it from 
Goto System Preference -> Keyboard -> Modify Keys then update your shortcut key according to your preference.

[image]

For additional info. Checkout this [shortcuts for xcode](https://ericasadun.com/2017/02/23/xcode-tricks-adding-keyboard-shortcuts/)

Comment: Since you added android studio tag, I gave this. Sorry my mistake

Comment: @ManojPerumarath this might be useful